# Initialize pid_t variable

Tags: c++, fork

I have an error reported by Valgrind:

```
==5644== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

This is happening for a variable of type `pid_t`.

My code is the following:

```
GmpPipePlayer::GmpPipePlayer( IOBase *pIO, Referee *pBack, PieceColor pc, int size, const DataBoard *pBd, int handicap, const char *cmd_line, int bDebug )
    : GmpPlayer(pIO, pBack, pc, size, pBd, handicap, bDebug)
{
    int down[2], up[2];
        pid_t _pid;  //here the var is declared

    pipe(down);   
    pipe(up);


    _pid = fork();

    if (_pid < 0)
        exit(1);


    if (_pid == 0)
    {
        close(down[1]);
        close(up[0]);

        dup2(down[0], 0);
        dup2(up[1], 1);

        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmd_line, NULL);

        _exit(1);
    }

    close(down[0]);
    close(up[1]);
    _down = down[1];
    _up = up[0];

    _reader_thd = new Thread(reader_wrapper, this);
}

GmpPipePlayer::~GmpPipePlayer()
{
    if (_pid > 0)   //valgrind is reporting that the error is here!!
    {
        kill(_pid, SIGTERM);
        _pid = 0;
    }

    if (_up)
    {
        close(_up);
        _up = 0;
    }

    if (_down)
    {
        close(_down);
        _down = 0;
    }   
       delete _reader_thd
}
```

So, I think the problem is the `_pid` is not initialized, how should initialize this variable?  I tried in this way:

```
 pid_t _pid=0;
```

but this is still causing the same error. That piece of code is called many times during the process.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have two variables called `_pid` - the local that you declared in the constructor:

```
pid_t _pid;  //here the var is declared
```

and the one that you access in the destructor:

```
if (_pid > 0)   //valgrind is reporting that the error is here!!
```

These variables are not the same: the one that you access in the destructor must be a global or an instance variable (more likely).

Since you rely on `_pid` to pass the state from the constructor to the destructor, you need to remove the local declaration from the constructor, and initialize the other `_pid` as appropriate. If it is an instance variable, add its initialization to the initializer list, like this:

```
GmpPipePlayer::GmpPipePlayer( IOBase *pIO, Referee *pBack, PieceColor pc, int size, const DataBoard *pBd, int handicap, const char *cmd_line, int bDebug )
: GmpPlayer(pIO, pBack, pc, size, pBd, handicap, bDebug), _pid(0) {
    ... //                         HERE ------------------^
}
```